# How to count how many times which class was used in runtime of Java app

Tags: java, class, count, profiling, classloader

I think I need to setup some profiler, or somehow configure the class loader to save this info. Here what I need:
When ever a JVM runs,I need to execute a process that keep track of java files being loaded by the class loader. Across all the threads (and processes also, but that is another JVM).

So in the output I need to have information how many times which class was used.

Can you offer some tools and configuration examples for these? That's better be a command line tool & free.

Comment: What do you mean with `how many times a class was used`: The number of instances being created? The number of method calls? The number of loaded versions (in case you have different classloaders)? And what do you need that information for?

Comment: I need info how many times the class was loaded. I need this info to have statistics (an internal task) which classes are used the most and which are not used at all.

Comment: Well, in that case just create a memory dump and analyize it. You should be able to see the class loader instances and the `Class` objects they reference. Normally each class is loaded once per class loader, however in some systems class loaders might refer to another one's class (e.g. JBoss class loaders would most certainly do that for `java.lang` classes etc.)

Comment: This is a common profiling task. There are a number of profilers, e. g. [YoutKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) or use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)/[jhat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html)

Comment: Are you asking because you have a larger goal, such as making the app run faster? Or are you just trying to eliminate unused classes?

Comment: The goal is to eliminate unused classes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Java Profiler.  Some open source options are [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers).

Answer (score 1):

Profilers will certainly give you that information, but you need to run the JVM under profiling, for which there is a performance cost.

If you are planning on collecting this information on-demand from production systems, you are probably going to need to instrument the classes/packages you are interested in with JMX.  Then you can use something like HP OpenView or Nagios to monitor the values.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09196/index.html talks about how getting started in JMX.  Perhaps the JVM already collects some of this stuff, I don't know.

The downside of the JMX approach is that you have to know beforehand what you want to collect and instrument the target classes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see which classes were loaded you can run with

```
java -verbose:class com.your.Class
```